# Deleting large records in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete, delete-row, large-data

I have `KPI_LOG` table which contains `600000` record and the table is growing is everytime. I have `TIME_STAMP` coulmn in this table which specify when the record is created and i have to delete records which is older than 2 days from this table. I am using below query to perform deletion :

`delete from KPI_LOG where SYSDATE - TIMESTAMP > 2;`

But as the number of records is too large it will take lot of time if i use simply Delete query for this case. I am looking for faster deletion for this purpose but didn't find any solution.

Comment: first things i would look at are...1. is there an index on your timestamp column?, 2. test a functional index for "timestamp -2" 3. google "oracle bulk delete" to see if anything there can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> delete from KPI_LOG where SYSDATE - TIMESTAMP > 2;

If you are deleting more number of rows then you are keeping in the table, then you could do a **CTAS** i.e. `create table as select` and then drop the old able and rename the new table.

Make sure, you have an **index** on the `timestamp` column.

For example,

```
CREATE INDEX tmstmp_indx ON KPI_LOG(TIMESTAMP )
/

CREATE TABLE KPI_LOG_NEW 
  AS 
 SELECT * FROM KPI_LOG WHERE TIMESTAMP > SYSDATE -2
/

DROP TABLE KPI_LOG
/

ALTER TABLE KPI_LOG_NEW RENAME TO KPI_LOG
/
```

Make sure you create all the necessary indexes and constraints on the new table.

Deleting rows doesn't reset the **HIGH WATERMARK**, by doing **CTAS** you have a fresh new table. Therefore, you don't have to scan all those rows below the high watermark which you would do in case of deletion.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting a record requires a transaction log record. This is integral to consistency.

This also means that deleting records is far from cheap - in a case like this, when a single statement deletes hundreds of thousands of rows, each of those rows needs to be written to the transaction log first. There is no way around this when you don't want to delete *all* the records.

If possible, you could simply call the delete command more often - the total time taken while deleting will not change much, but each command will take much shorter time (as long as you have proper indices).

Answer (score 0):

If you have an ID as primary key of which data is in ascending order (sequence for example), you can select the min and max value of that ID column in the interval you want to delete.

Then the database engine doesn't have to compare dates, but primary key values!

There is no quicker way, as the primary key is a clustered index, meaning the records is phisically next to each other on the server.

You would need PL/SQL block to do that.